# Problem using "sudo su" command

Tags: root

When I use "sudo su" cmd termianl asks for the root passwd. But after one successful login it never asks for authentication again. I want it to ask for authentication everytime.

Comment: Are you aware what you are trying to do with `sudo su`?

Comment: [There is never a really good reason to use `sudo su`.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/218169/22222)

Answer (score 4):

There are two things which you may be referring to here:

If you want to run one single command as root, run `sudo <command>`. Once that command finishes, you will lose root privileges. for example, you might run `sudo whoami` - the `whoami` command shows who you are logged in as. `sudo whoami` should show you are root, and when `whoami` is done, you will lose root privileges.

`su`, however, runs `bash` (or an equivalent shell). `bash` will then ask you, as root, what commands you want to run. To exit `su` and `bash`, just type `exit`; you will lose your privileges, and return to normal.

The other possibility is that sudo may be caching your authentication. This normally lasts 5 minutes from when you typed in your password, or when you run `sudo -k`. Or, you can disable this entirely by adding the following line to the file /etc/sudoers: `timestamp_timeout=0`

Answer (score 0):

`sudo su` command allows you to login into root account.After successful login it don't asks for authentication again.

If you want authentication for everytime then you have to exit out of the root account by running `exit` command.

Answer (score 0):

While using "sudo" command, u will be asked for a password. Once a user has been authenticated, a timestamp is updated and the user may then use sudo without a password for a short period of time (possibly 5 mins). so it will ask password after that time expires.